# Why is Snorkmaiden called "Floren" in the Japanese audio track for the TV show Moomin from 1990?

Tags: moomin

In the English translations of the *Moomin* books that I have read her name is always "Snorkmaiden".

[Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Moomin_characters#Close_friends) that in Finnish she is "Niiskuneiti" and in Swedish "Snorkfröken".

I have found other names for her [here](https://www.moomin.com/en/characters/snorkmaiden/):

- German: Snorkfräulein
- French: la Demoiselle Snorque
- Italian: Grugnina
- Russian: Фрекен Снорк
- Polish: Panna Migotka
- Icelandic: Snorkstelpan
- Dutch: Snork-meisje
- Estonian: Tusklikupreili

But bewilderingly in the first episode of [*Moomin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moomin_(1990_TV_series)) she is referred to as "Floren" in the Japanese audio (it is also spelled out in the English subtitles.) Where does this name come from?

Answer (score 1):

In Polish "Panna Migotka" translate to "Miss Blinky". So nothing in common with a "snork" but because she wears a "golden" ankle band.

And Floren? I would say it's same mind set as in Polish. Snorkmaiden have three distinctive elements: Blonde hair, jewellery and flowers. So flowers > floral > Floren.

In Polis "snork" translate to same word as smoking pipe - "fajka". And that's pretty bad name for a girl.

Comment: I like your logic, I think you are probably correct about the reasoning. I'm hoping someone can find a translator's note or similar that confirms this.